# Javascript reference error/element is null/element is undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a review page where i have peoples' names, images, and the review they left. Then there are two arrow buttons to scroll to the next or previous review then a bigger button that gives you a random review every time you click it.

The problem is I keep getting a reference error or element is null, or element is undefined. I've tried so many things and I can't seem to figure it out, ill leave the relevant parts of my html and JS code

```
  <body>
    <main>
      <div class="title">
        <h2>Our Reviews</h2>
        <div class="underline"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src=./person-1.jpeg id="person-img" alt="Image of reviewer">
        </div>

        <div class="profile">
          <h4 id="author">Sara Jones</h4>
          <p id="job-title">Web Developer</p>
        </div>

        <div id="info">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur id officia alias est earum illo optio asperiores eius culpa magni provident, distinctio dolore illum numquam eligendi. Aperiam cum odit eius.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="chevron">
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-left prev-btn"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-right next-btn"></i>
        </div>

        <button id="surprise">Suprise me</button>
      </div>
    </main>

    <!-- javascript -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
```

for my JS, i have an aray of four objects each containin the name,image,job title,a unique id and the review left by each person

```
 // set initial item
const currentItem = 0;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  // get items
  const author = document.getElementById('#author');
  const job = document.getElementById('#job-title');
  const img = document.getElementById('#person-img');
  const info = document.querySelector('.info');

  const prev = document.querySelector('.prev-btn');
  const next = document.querySelector('.next-btn');
  const button = document.getElementById('#surprise');
  
  // display current item
  showPerson(currentItem);

  // listen for button click
  button.addEventListener('click', function(){

  // generate and display random item 
  const getRandomReview = reviews[getRandomNumber()]
  showPerson(getRandomReview);


  })
})


// generate random number
const getRandomNumber = () => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random * reviews.length);
} 

// display item
const showPerson = (person) => {
  const item = reviews[person];
  img.src = item.img;
  author.textContent = item.name;
  job.textContent = item.job;
  info.textContent = item.text;
}
```

Comment: It sould be `document.getElementById('author');` without the `#`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the `#` symbol when using `getElementById`.  You just need the id value itself.

Either remove the `#` or use `querySelector` instead.

```
const author = document.getElementById('author');
```

OR

```
const author = document.querySelector('#author');
```